# Androidplot - fullscreen graph widget

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I am trying to make the graph widget fill the view, I managed to make the labels and titles transparent, but there is still a blank space where they are. How could I remove them post 1.0?

Image of what I am trying to remove:

[image: Image of what I am trying to remove]

Comment: well according to what you have given you can achieve that by redrawing an image using that red line as you need .. or you can post what you have done

Comment: well I am actually trying to remove the spaces I marked on the plot in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this to set your Plot's style in xml to `FullScreenGraph`:

```
style="@style/FullScreenGraph"
```

Or if you prefer you can copy the relevant elements from the style def to your style to get the same effect:

```
<style name="FullScreenGraph">
    <item name="graphMarginTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="graphMarginBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="graphMarginLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="graphMarginRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="graphHeightMode">fill</item>
    <item name="graphWidthMode">fill</item>
    <item name="graphHeight">0</item>
    <item name="graphWidth">0</item>
    <item name="domainLineThickness">1dp</item>
    <item name="graphHorizontalPositioning">absolute_from_left</item>
    <item name="graphVerticalPositioning">absolute_from_top</item>
    <item name="rangeLineThickness">1dp</item>
    <item name="graphAnchor">left_top</item>
    <item name="graphHorizontalPosition">0dp</item>
    <item name="graphVerticalPosition">0dp</item>
    <item name="legendVisible">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank You.